# Recover lost .bashrc

Tags: bash, ubuntu, .bash-profile

So I did something exceedingly stupid and now my .bashrc file is gone. Is there any way for me to recover it? I still have a terminal window open that uses the old bashrc file. If there's no way for me to recover it all (as I imagine there isn't) what else should I copy to a new .bashrc besides the old `$PATH`? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 if there is an OS-specific solution.

Comment: `set` can tell you a bit more than sole $PATH.

Comment: You're probably better off asking on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). There's a [related question there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24586/bashrc-overwritten-but-still-sourced-how-can-it-be-recovered)

Comment: the best you can do (I think) is capture the state of your open window session. `export > export_list.txt; set > set_list.txt; functions > func_list.txt; alias > alias_list.txt` might get you most of what was there. Any logic will have to be rebuilt. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu uses `/etc/skel/.bashrc` as the base `.bashrc` that gets copied into every new users home directory. Unless you have made custom changes you can simply copy `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to your home directory and you will be set. If you have made custom changes then you will need to make them again.